# PHP different behavior when page not requested from a browser

Tags: php, mysql, apache

We're writing a simple video player, and part of its functionality is to send a simple GET request to a PHP page on the web server, to update the database with the customer's activity (i.e., the ID of the video they are watching, what position they are, and their user ID):

```
listener.php?user=1&time=59000&movie_id=35003
```

this listener.php is very simple, it checks if there already exists a row for this particular user ID and movie ID:

```
SELECT orders_products_id,
    products_date_last_watched as lasttime,
    now() as now,
    products_timewatched
  from orders_products
    where products_id = '" . $product_id . "' and
    customers_id = '" . $customer_id ."'
```

followed by:

```
if ($check['orders_products_id'] > 0)
```

If true, it will run an UPDATE statement

if false, it will run an INSERT statement

Now, the problem is, if I load this listener.php in my browser and change values directly in the URL, it works as expected.

But, when the same page is called by the program, it always ends up inserting a new row. The server's logs show the correct URL:

```
"GET /listener.php?user=1&time=128142&movie_id=35003 HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
```

Any ideas? This is running on my test server which is XAMPP on Windows 2008R2 , if that makes any difference?

Edit: here is the full code:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");

include('includes/application_top.php');


$user_id = $_GET['user'];
$lastpos = $_GET['time'];
$product_id = $_GET['movie_id'];
$episode = 0;

//check for existing listing
$check_query = tep_db_query("SELECT orders_products_id, products_date_last_watched as lasttime, now() as now, products_timewatched from orders_products where products_id = '" . $product_id . "' and customers_id = '" . $customer_id ."' and products_lastepisode = '" . $episode . "'");
$check = tep_db_fetch_array($check_query);

if ($check['orders_products_id'] > 0) {
//user has already watched this


//find seconds between last timestamp and now
$starttime = strtotime($check['lasttime']);
$endtime = strtotime($check['now']);
$difference = $endtime - $starttime;

if ($difference < 60) {
    $totaltime = $check['products_timewatched'] + $difference;
} else {
    $totaltime = $check['products_timewatched'];
}

$update_query = "UPDATE orders_products set products_lastposition = '" . $lastpos ."', products_date_last_watched = now(), products_lastepisode = '" . $episode . "', products_timewatched = '" . $totaltime . "', products_platform = '" . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . "', customers_ip = '" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ."' where orders_products_id = '" . $check['orders_products_id'] ."'";
tep_db_query($update_query);

} else {

//create new entry
if ($user_id != 999999999){
    tep_db_query("INSERT INTO orders_products (products_date_first_watched, products_visible, products_date_last_watched, customers_id, products_id, products_lastposition, products_lastepisode, products_timewatched) values (now(), 1, now(), '" . $user_id . "', '" . $product_id . "', '" . $lastpos ."', '" . $episode . "', 0)");
}
}
```

Some notes:
 - "tep_db_query" for the mysql queries because I am using modified version of osCommerce's functions, it's functionally the same as the standard mysql_query and mysql_fetch_array
 - user id 99999999 means it is a guest user and their activity should not be recorded
 - the whole "//find seconds between last timestamp and now" is to keep track of the total time spend

Comment: Can you post the complete script?

Comment: echo the query as debug to the error log. I bet you don't get the right parameters?

Comment: well time will always be different since he is using `NOW()` from MySQL function and not from a date field he have.

Comment: @j08691 full code pasted

Comment: @Nanne How could I do that, it would certainly help!

Comment: @Prix yes I am getting now() from the db to be sure there's no discrepancy from PHP's time functions

Comment: @eTiMaGo: "How could I do that" --- with `echo`?

Answer (score 0):

nevermind, I am an idiot... the URL variable is $user_id but I looked up $customer_id in the SQL query... *facepalm*